# how to clean up youtube embed video

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

Im trying to upload a video from youtube to other site. How can we get rid of "watch later" and "share" and also the watch on youtube. And also the coverphoto i want to use like time 1:00

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Because you embed it using YouTube, they can show what they want. So you cannot remove these buttons.

Comment: theres a parameter for that